# Parse increment two fields at the same time. One field dependent on the other

Tags: parse-platform, increment

I have an object in Parse where I keep an average score. The object has two fields: "count" and "average". 
Every time the user posts a new score, I need to update the running average. Example, if count=3 and average = 10, then posting a new score of 20 needs to set count=4 and average = 12.5.

Now this is an average of multiple users. How do I block other users from updating the "count" field, while I am reading "count", using it to compute and update "average"?

Thanks in advance.
Zak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It's not pretty, but works.

I don't store the average anymore. Instead, I store "count" and "runningscore". Runningscore is a total of the scores. Then, while displaying in the app, I compute the average using count and runningscore (instead of storing the average). Count and runningscore can be incremented with no problem.